# ImageJ: NameError when using selectionType() in Python script

Tags: python, jython, imagej, imagej-macro

I am a newbie to ImageJ and was trying to recreate the following macro using Python (in ImageJ macro editor).

```
s = selectionType();

if( s == -1 ) {
    exit("There was no selection.");
} else if( s != 10 ) {
    exit("The selection wasn't a point selection.");
} else {
    getSelectionCoordinates(xPoints,yPoints);
    x = xPoints[0];
    y = yPoints[0];
    showMessage("Got coordinates ("+x+","+y+")");
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to import selectionType() and getSelectionCoordinates() builtin functions. I get NameError when I try to use them in the Python Code.

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, ImageJ 1.x's built-in macro functions are not first-class Java methods, and hence not necessarily available from other script languages such as Python.

You can read the Java source to see what the macro functions do, but it takes some effort in some cases to decipher. E.g., the `getSelectionCoordinates` function can be [seen here](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.51h/src/main/java/ij/macro/Functions.java#L1309-L1346).

In short: it calls the `getRoi()` method of `ImagePlus` and then depending what kind of `Roi` it is, populates the coordinates differently. For `Roi.LINE` type, the `x1d`, `y1d`, `x2d` and `y2d` fields are used. Otherwise, the `getFloatPolygon()` method of `Roi` is called to convert the ROI to a polygon type, and then its coordinates are walked.

For the `selectionType` function, just call `getRoi()` on the `ImagePlus`.